# Oracle 12.1 - update column max value dynamically

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Sometimes I need to set number type column value as max value

Because I need to allow all values and I can't use negative value. Examples:

For number(1) -> 9

For number(1,2) -> 9.99

Can I update column max value dynamically based on column type?

```
   Update table set x= ?maxvalue?
```

Comment: Which oracle version are you using?

Comment: @tejash 12.1 version

Comment: Just for an information, NUMBER(1,2) will not accept 9.99. It will throw error, "Value larger than precision". Max value in this case will be 0.09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use default value.

```
Alter table your_table modify your_col number(1) default 9;
```

Now, you can update value to default value.

```
Update your_table 
Set your_col = default
Where ..
```

Same way you can do it for column with data type `number(1,2)` with default value as `9.99`

Cheers!!

Comment: No, I am talking about [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd858ca7d0d549a516cbd24409b14d99)